# File Uploads & Chrome (BROWSER) running out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

In my web app that allows file uploads, I'm noticing that continued use of several file uploads (each about 5mb to 15mb) causes my browser to crash with what looks to be a "out of memory" issue.

After each file upload by reading into Buffer memory, do I need to do any clean up tasks after?

Also how can I see what's currently inside my browser memory in my web app?

Comment: don't read each file into memory, xhr.send(theFile) to chunk the upload. a lot of folks don't realize you can send() Files and Blobs, but the browser takes care of all the heavy lifting when you do so, and it works amazing. i've uploaded multi-gig movie files like this, but FileReader() maxes out at about 20 megs on a good day. FileReader() also slows down the UI, but sending binary File handles does not.

Comment: @dandavis - This is good to hear and should be posted as an answer.  The only problem with this is that if the user selects multiple files or a directory and also wants to send meta data along with the raw file data then it must be done it multiple passes.  I think I will have to send the file structure meta data as JSON and have the server send back an array of UUIDs which can then be appended to the upload path to send each file's data separately.

Comment: @NickSotiros: in that case, you can use a populated <form> `xhr.send(elmForm)`, with all the file inputs and meta as plain hidden input fields. it should arrive to server just like a normal POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a file, you have to close(), destroy(), abort(), all the objects that you are using, I had a similar problem 1 month ago, and I fixed it aborting and closing all the objects after file has been uploaded. When you upload a file is necessary do it ! I hope that my answer help you